# vb c# IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#

I cant save file. Please help. Here's my code

```
private void cmdsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //x = 0;
    con();
    sqlcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE PCode = '" + txtlname.Text + "' AND PName = '" + txtfname.Text + "' AND Quantity = '" + txtmname.Text + "' AND Section = '" + textBox2.Text + "' ";
    sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
        OleDbDataReader reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {x++;}
    if (x != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate record(s) found...");                
    }
    else
    {
        if (mode == "a")
        {   
            con();
            sqlcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblname (PCode, PName, Quantity, Section) VALUES ('" + txtlname.Text + "', '" + txtfname.Text + "', '" + txtmname.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "') ";
            sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
            reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Record(s) Saved", "Sample");
        }
        else if (mode == "e")
        {
            con();
            sqlcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE tblname SET PCode = '" + txtlname.Text + "', PName = '" + txtfname.Text + "', Quantity = '" + txtmname.Text + "' , Section = '" + textBox2.Text + "' WHERE ID = " + idholder + "  ";
            sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
            reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Record(s) Updated", "Sample");
        }
    }
    connect.Close();
    idholder = "";
    cncel();     
}
```

I just add the section(textBox2) on that. Before adding those code, the program run correctly.

[image]

Comment: The *first* thing you should fix is the SQL injection vulnerability. Use parameterized SQL. Next, edit your question to show the full stack trace of the exception *as text*. There's no need for a screenshot here, and the screenshot doesn't show the exception message, making it less helpful than it might be...

Comment: Maybe `Section` is a reserved keyword in your DBMS?  So you might need to either put it in brackets or single quotes also depending on your DBMS. `[Section]` or maybe `'Section'`.  My guess is based on [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1225443.aspx?Error+IErrorInfo+GetDescription+failed+with+E_FAIL+0x80004005+) which was the first result from googling that error message.

Comment: So i found out that my problem is this, everytime I add this code: 
    "'AND Section = '" + txtSec.Text + "'
on the  sqlcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM invento WHERE PCode = '" + txtlname.Text + "' AND PName = '" + txtfname.Text + "' AND Quantity = '" + txtmname.Text + "'";

the error will come out

Comment: @juharr thankyou sir! Its a reserved word.